# CKEditor - pasting from text file then applying bullets causes strange effect

Tags: ckeditor

Using CKEditor and I am copying a bunch of text on different lines into the editor. After I do that I select the text and click to apply bullets. The bullets appear but it throws the whole thing into a weird format.

Basically If I have 3 lines, the bullets appear for all 3 lines. But for the first 2 there is a line break after the bullet and the text is on the line underneath the bullet. Except on the 3rd one which looks fine

So

```
test1
test2
test3
```

when I try to apply bullets/numbering becomes

```
1.
   test1
2. 
   test2
3. test3
```

Havent been able to find anything on google yet. Anyone know how to stop this?

EDIT:

Added the html before an after.

Before:

```
<html data-version="ckeditor"><body><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-size:11pt">test1<br />
test2<br />
test3</span></span></span></body></html>"
```

After:

- test1
- test2
- test3

```
<html data-version="ckeditor"><body><ul>
<li><br />
<span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-size:11pt">test1</span></span></span></li>
<li><br />
<span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">test2</span></span></li>
<li><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">test3</span></span></li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you show your source(html) before and after ?

Comment: Ive updated the original post with the before and after

Comment: As you can see, problem that ckeditor preserves br tags, you should check your filtering rules, may be apply new for replacing <br> tags,  https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter, especially - https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFilter

Comment: I already have forcePasteAsPlainText turned on. So no tags should be coming across at all. I dont think the tag is getting pasted in, I think thats how a carriage return is interpreted in the editor. I need to be able to remove them tags when I apply the bullets/numbering. Its strange that the tags are put before the text though, how could that happen?

Comment: If you can repeat this situation here http://nightly.ckeditor.com/ you should write bag to CKEditor team, also check this may be it's related to your problem https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1013